# Calculating volume of a 2 variable definite integral using the midpoint rule of Riemann Summs

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to approximate the volume of a 2 variable definite integral  `sin^2(x)-cos^2(y)` using `while` and `for` loops. I've changed the code quite often and with the most recent change, it broke. I am very new to python so I'm still figuring out how to work with arrays properly.

This is what I have untill now (EDIT: With alani's comment I managed to fix the error, but now I'm not receiving an answer when running the code)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate


def f(x,y):
    return np.sin(x)**2-np.cos(y)**2

print(scipy.integrate.dblquad(f,0,1,0,2))
    
def Riemann(x0,xn,y0,yn,N):
    e = 1; 
    while e > 1e-3:
        x = np.linspace(0,1,N)
        y = np.linspace(0,2,N)
        dx = (x0-xn)/N
        dy = (y0-yn)/N
        for i in range(N):
            V = (dx*dy)*(f(x,y))
            np.sum(V)
            e = abs(1-V)
print(Riemann(0,1,0,2,1000))
```

When running this code I receive:

```
(-0.2654480895858587, 9.090239973208559e-15)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-c654507b2f73> in <module>
     19             np.sum(V)
     20             e = abs(1-V)
---> 21 print(Riemann(0,1,0,2,10))
     22 
     23 

<ipython-input-9-c654507b2f73> in Riemann(x0, xn, y0, yn, N)
     10 def Riemann(x0,xn,y0,yn,N):
     11     e = 1;
---> 12     while e > 1e-3:
     13         x = np.linspace(0,1,N)
     14         y = np.linspace(0,2,N)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: I haven't looked in detail, but it may be that if you use `np.sin` instead of `math.sin` (and similarly `cos` ) then it will work. The functions in numpy are designed to operate on arrays (returning element-by-element sine etc) whereas the ones in `math` take single values.

Comment: By the way, if you have broken your code by making a change and don't have the old version, this strongly suggests that you would do well at this stage to look into using some kind of source code version management, such as `git`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple issues, I'll address them so that you can improve. First off all, the formatting is pretty terrible. Put spaces after commas, separate things more with white-space, etc. You can see the difference in my code, and I'm by no means an expert at code formatting.

Second, your method is not doing what you think it's doing. Every time you iterate `i`, you create an entire array of values and you assign it to V, since `x` and `y` are both arrays. Neither `x` nor `y` are being updated here. The loop does the same thing every time, and V get re-assigned the same value every time. `np.sum(V)` never gets assigned anywhere, so the only thing getting updated *at all* in that loop is `e`. Of course, that bit is incorrect since you cannot subtract a vector from a scalar, since, as I wrote above, V is a vector.

Your function didn't use `x0`, `y0`, etc. for your bounds of integration, since your linspaces were hardcoded.

Now we come to the solution. There are two approaches to this problem. There's the "slow" pure Python way, where we just loop over our y's and x's and take function values multiplied by the base `dx * dy`. That version looks like this:

```
# This a naive version, using two for loops. It's very slow.
def Riemann(x0, xn, y0, yn, N):
    xs = np.linspace(x0, xn, N)
    ys = np.linspace(y0, yn, N)
    dx = (x0 - xn) / N
    dy = (y0 - yn) / N
    V = 0
    for y in ys:
        for x in xs:
            V += f(x, y)
    return dx * dy * V
```

Note I moved the multiplication outside to save some on performance.

The other way is to use numpy, that version looks like this:

```
def Riemann(x0, xn, y0, yn, N):
    points = itertools.product(np.linspace(x0, xn, N), np.linspace(y0, yn, N))
    points = np.array(list(points))
    xs = points[:, 0]
    ys = points[:, 1]
    dx = (x0 - xn) / N
    dy = (y0 - yn) / N
    return dx * dy * np.sum(f(xs, ys))
```

Here we avoid the double for-loop. Note that you must include `import itertools` for this to work. Here we use the Cartesian product to create all points we wish to evaluate, and then give those points to your function `f` which is designed to work with numpy arrays. We get a vector back from `f` of all the function values at each point, and we simply just sum all the elements, just like we did in the for-loop. Then we can multiply by the common base `dx * dy` and return that.

The only thing I do not understand about your code is what you want `e` to do, and how it relates to `N`. I'm guessing it's some sort of error tolerance, but why you were trying to subtract the total volume so far (even if your code did nothing of the sort) from 1 I can't understand.